# Error using VideoReader in MATLAB 2017b mac

Tags: macos, matlab

I am trying to use VideoReader in Matlab R2017b in Mac 10.13.2 to read a .avi file but it gives me error as follows:

```html
Error using VideoReader/init (line 619)
Could not read file due to an unexpected error. Reason: Cannot Decode

Error in VideoReader (line 172)
            obj.init(fileName);

Error in Project1 (line 3)
vidObj = VideoReader('jan28.avi')
```

I tried referring to multiple stack overflow questions but unable to find a solution. Please help me in reading and processing the .avi file.

Below is aviinfo output of the avi file that I'm using in the sample

```html
>> aviinfo('jan28.avi')
Warning: AVIINFO will be removed in a future release. Use VIDEOREADER instead. 
> In aviinfo (line 66) 

ans = 

  struct with fields:

              Filename: '/Users/nagakukunuru/Matlab_work/jan28.avi'
              FileSize: 8642702
           FileModDate: '26-Jan-2018 02:13:59'
             NumFrames: 1600
       FramesPerSecond: 30
                 Width: 704
                Height: 480
             ImageType: 'truecolor'
      VideoCompression: 'XVID'
               Quality: 100
    NumColormapEntries: 0
```

Comment: what encoder are you using for the video? A better way of asking, How are you acquiring your videos? I ask because some encoders cannot be opened by matlab.

Comment: I'm able to use the same avi file in windows but I'm unable use the same in mac to read using videoreader

Comment: that suggests you are using a windows specific encoder (probably xvid). Can you re-encode it using Avidemux? I usually use h264 as it is generally readable on all operating systems.

Comment: Yes, it is having Encoder as xvid. I edited my question with the info of the file. How can I make use of the same file without re-encoding it.

Comment: After doing some digging, it appears that VideoReader is using the operating systems API to do the reading. If this is correct then you can only open files which the operating system can open. As xvid is windows proprietary, I don't know if mac will be able to open. I will look around more for more details.

Comment: Can we convert the file programmatically in Matlab i.e., if it cannot be decoded then re-encode it programmatically and use it with VideoReader?

Comment: If matlab cannot decode it then it cannot re-encode it for the videoReader. You will have to use Avidemux or virtualdub or other video editing software to re-encode the file.